# HTML Submit Button Not Working (not PHP/JavaScript related)

Tags: html, forms, submit

I have looked over all your suggestions as to an answer to my question, but every question asked on this subject also uses PHP or JavaScript.  I do not use either of these, so none of the available answers helps me in any way.

My problem is the same, except that I'm making an HTML form. I have my opening form code as:

```
<form action="mailto:dj.*******@*****.com" method="post" target="_blank" id="JewelryPoll" title="My Jewelry Poll">
```

and my submit button as:

```
<input name="SUBMIT" type="submit" id="SUBMIT" title="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT" align="center">
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I tried putting value as my email.  I even tried putting "method=get" on it as well, and that didn't do anything either.

I do not use PHP as I don't know it.  I do not use JavaScript as I don't know enough of it to be able to use it.  I used to know how to make the "submit" button work only with HTML, but my memory lapses prevent me from remembering some things.

Can you help with this please?  I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong as to why it isn't working.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Jewelry Poll</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="mailto:dj.squeakey@gmail.com" method="post" target="_blank" id="JewelryPoll" title="My Jewelry Poll">
<label><h1 align="center">Of the answers below, which types of handmade beaded jewelry would you be willing to purchase if the price were right?</h1></label>
<p align="center"><input name="Bracelets" type="checkbox" id="Bracelets" title="Bracelets" value="Bracelets" checked>Bracelets<br>
<input name="Earrings" type="checkbox" id="Earrings" title="Earrings" value="Earrings">Earrings<br>
<input name="Necklaces" type="checkbox" id="Necklaces" title="Necklaces" value="Necklaces">Necklaces<br>
<input name="Rings" type="checkbox" id="Rings" title="Rings" value="Rings" checked>Rings<br>
<input name="Watches" type="checkbox" id="Watches" title="Watches" value="Watches">Watches<br>
<input name="BESet" type="checkbox" id="BESet" title="Bracelet/Earring Set" value="BESet">Bracelet/Earring Set<br>
<input name="BNSet" type="checkbox" id="BNSet" title="Bracelet/Necklace Set" value="BNSet">Bracelet/Necklace Set<br>
<input name="BRSet" type="checkbox" id="BRSet" title="Bracelet/Ring Set" value="BRSet">Bracelet/Ring Set<br>
<input name="BWSet" type="checkbox" id="BWSet" title="Bracelet/Watch Set" value="BWSet" checked>Bracelet/Watch Set<br>
<input name="BENSet" type="checkbox" id="BENSet" title="Bracelet/Earring/Necklace Set" value="BENSet">Bracelet/Earring/Necklace Set<br>
<input name="BENRSet" type="checkbox" id="BENRSet" title="Bracelet/Earring/Necklace/Ring Set" value="BENRSet">Bracelet/Earring/Necklace/Ring Set<br>
<input name="BENRWSet" type="checkbox" id="BENRWSet" title="Bracelet/Earring/Necklace/Ring/Watch Set" value="BENRWSet">Bracelet/Earring/Necklace/Ring/Watch Set<br>
<input name="BENWSet" type="checkbox" id="BENWSet" title="Bracelet/Earring/Necklace/Watch Set" value="BENWSet">Bracelet/Earring/Necklace/Watch Set<br>
<input name="BERSet" type="checkbox" id="BERSet" title="Bracelet/Earring/Ring Set" value="BERSet">Bracelet/Earring/Ring Set<br>
<input name="BEWSet" type="checkbox" id="BEWSet" title="Bracelet/Earring/Watch Set" value="BEWSet">Bracelet/Earring/Watch Set<br>
<input name="BNRSet" type="checkbox" id="BNRSet" title="Bracelet/Necklace/Ring Set" value="BNRSet">Bracelet/Necklace/Ring Set<br>
<input name="BNWSet" type="checkbox" id="BNWSet" title="Bracelet/Necklace/Watch Set" value="BNWSet">Bracelet/Necklace/Watch Set<br>
<input name="BRWSet" type="checkbox" id="BRWSet" title="Bracelet/Ring/Watch Set" value="BRWSet" checked>Bracelet/Ring/Watch Set<br>
<input name="BERWSet" type="checkbox" id="BERWSet" title="Bracelet/Earring/Ring/Watch Set" value="BERWSet">Bracelet/Earring/Ring/Watch Set<br>
<input name="ENSet" type="checkbox" id="ENSet" title="Earring/Necklace Set" value="ENSet">Earring/Necklace Set<br>
<input name="ERSet" type="checkbox" id="ERSet" title="Earring/Ring Set" value="ERSet">Earring/Ring Set<br>
<input name="EWSet" type="checkbox" id="EWSet" title="Earring/Watch Set" value="EWSet">Earring/Watch Set<br>
<input name="ENRSet" type="checkbox" id="ENRSet" title="Earring/Necklace/Ring Set" value="ENRSet">Earring/Necklace/Ring Set<br>
<input name="ENWSet" type="checkbox" id="ENWSet" title="Earring/Necklace/Watch Set" value="ENWSet">Earring/Necklace/Watch Set<br>
<input name="ERWSet" type="checkbox" id="ERWSet" title="Earring/Ring/Watch Set" value="ERWSet">Earring/Ring/Watch Set<br>
<input name="NRSet" type="checkbox" id="NRSet" title="Necklace/Ring Set" value="NRSet">Necklace/Ring Set<br>
<input name="NWSet" type="checkbox" id="NWSet" title="Necklace/Watch Set" value="NWSet">Necklace/Watch Set<br>
<input name="NRWSet" type="checkbox" id="NRWSet" title="Necklace/Ring/Watch Set" value="NRWSet">Necklace/Ring/Watch Set<br>
<input name="RWSet" type="checkbox" id="RWSet" title="Ring/Watch Set" value="RWSet">Ring/Watch Set<br>
<input name="Any" type="checkbox" id="Any" title="Anything as long as its beautifully made by you" value="Any" checked>Anything as long as its beautifully made by you.<br><br><br>
<TEXTAREA NAME="comment" ROWS=8 COLS=100>Please leave any comments here
</TEXTAREA><br><br><br>
<input name="SUBMIT" type="submit" id="SUBMIT" title="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT" align="center"><br>
<input name="RESET" type="reset" id="RESET" title="RESET" value="RESET" align="center"><br></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the entire code and which browser you are testing in.

Comment: I test in all browsers.  I have the list set up in my Dreamweaver to be able to test it in any browser that I know exists.  I have added the full coding of the page to my original post.  As for where my site is located, it is hosted on Doteasy.com.  They have several add-ons that I could use to build this type of form, but I just don't understand how to use them, and all the demo's are blank and not showing anything for me to be able to see the outcome.  Also, these add-ons only allow 5 entries, not the 30 that I have listed above.

Comment: id's should always be unique

Comment: so they should not be the same as the input name?  I was trying to follow an example form that I found on the net, but apparently I got lost somewhere in the coding or something, but it just isn't working for me.

Comment: Meaning, no two elements can have the same `id`. Honestly, you don't even need to give any element an id unless you have a specific reason to. In any case it would not be related to your issue. By the way, your code works for me in Chrome and launches Gmail.

Comment: ok, so any suggestions as to what would be causing it not to work?  I did exactly as the site that I went to said to, for making an HTML form, but all they said do for the "submit" button, is exactly how I have it coded.  They didn't say anything else would be needed.  I really could use some help here in making this work, as I'd like to get my jewelry selling, and not just sitting on the site doing nothing.

Comment: @CutiePengu What is your default email client? In any case, even if you get it working don't expect it to work for others, see Quentin's answer.

Comment: My email client is gmail.  I have used it for years.  When I made forms before I forgot how, I would always get them.  Like I said, I used to know how to do it, but with memory lapses, I forgot how to make them work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `mailto:` as a form action [simply doesn't work](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html).

You **must** use some form of server side programming to send email from a form.

That could be JavaScript, PHP or any other programming language.

It could be code you write yourself. It could be code written by a third party.

It could be code you host yourself. It could be code hosted by a third party.

Comment: Are you sure? It "works" for me in Chrome an FF. (meaning, it opens an email client with the form values ready to send) I definitely don't suggest using it but at least it should *do something* if coded correctly. "Simply doesn't work" is misleading.

Comment: @WesleyMurch — the article linked to elaborates. In short, there are too many people on the WWW using systems which don't have a browser/email client combination that will support this.

Comment: This is a poll that I'm putting up on my site for my visitors to vote in.  I make beaded jewelry and I want people's opinions on what they would purchase, so I know what to make.  No one seems to understand that I want the results to be sent to my email.  When I click on the submit button, it don't do anything except open a blank page, and thats not what I am trying to do.

Comment: This is really the only answer that gives proper direction. mailto forms are not reliable or user friendly. Learn a little PHP.

Comment: No, what you want is quite clear. The answer is still "Start using a server side programming language".

Comment: @CutiePengu "It doesn't do anything" is not the same as "it opens a blank page". Anyways, trust me, this HTML-only contact form won't work. Learn a little PHP or use something like this: http://www.wufoo.com/

Comment: I don't know what that is or how to code it.  I have my main site hosted by Doteasy.com.  Do I need to find out from them why its not working, or is it my coding that is causing it not to work properly.  I have had my site here for years and never had problems with forms before.  Of course I didn't have memory problems like I do now, either.

Comment: It's not working because `mailto:` depends on very specific browser / email client configurations that a huge proportion of people don't have.

Comment: Ok, how about this.  What if I use the email that is set up for my site with Doteasy.com?  Will that work with my coding or not?

Comment: The email address you send it to has nothing to do with the problem, which is related to the software that the visitor is using.