# setting a submit button from my simple form to send to my email (current code included)

Tags: html, forms, submit

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I'm just trying to get the submit button to send the information to my email. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for all the table code, had to be a table for an assignment.

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:suzanne@nielsenwebdesigns.com" > <table width="478" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="166" style="font-family: 'Letter Gothic Std', 'Lithos Pro Regular', 'Mesquite Std', 'Trebuchet MS'">Name:
</td>
<td width="281">
<input name="name" type="text" required id="name" title="name" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:
</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" required id="email" title="email" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone:</td>
<td><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subject:</td>
<td><select name="subject" required id="subject" title="subject">
     <option value="info">General Information</option>
     <option value="web design">Web Design</option>
     <option value="hosting">Hosting services</option>
     <option value="logo design">Logo Design</option>
     </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>How did you hear of us?</td>
<td>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="how did you hear" value="friend" id="howdidyouhear_0">
friend
</label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="how did you hear" value="search" id="howdidyouhear_1">
search
</label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="how did you hear" value="ad" id="howdidyouhear_2">
ad
</label>

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Message:</td>
<td><textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="15" id="message" title="message"> 
</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="clear" type="image" id="clear" src="clear.png" alt="clear" /></td>
<td>
<input name="submit" type="image" id="submit" src="submit.png" alt="submit" value="send email" />
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Web emailing is really this easy? Wow, I may have missed something

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Submit Button Not Working (not PHP/JavaScript related)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409627/html-submit-button-not-working-not-php-javascript-related)

Comment: @Poomrokc The 3years :Why comment if you're going to be rude? I left out the middle content of the code because I didn't think it needed to be seen.

Comment: @Suzanne Alright, I'm sorry. I just need you to provide clearer problem. Is it the form not submit,submit but not send data, send data but not sending email? I'm really sorry about my first comment, On first glance I think that there is a new api that can send email this way.

Comment: @Poomrokc The 3years , I appreciate the apology. I will add my whole code for my contact form. My problem is the submit button does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

are you dutch? a lot of dutch people have that name ;) )
I think what you're trying to do is send information which is in an input field to your e-mail adress. You can do this using PHP and maybe some other solution, but i dont know them.
For sending the mail with php i would recommend using something like this:

first change the html to:

```
    <form action="mail.php" method="post">
    <textarea cols='40' rows='7' name='mailcontent'></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Then create a file called "mail.php" and add this code to it:

```
    <?php
        $mail_content = $_POST['mailcontent'];
        $mail_subject = "a subject you like, can not be removed."
        $mail_to = "suzanne@nielsenwebdesigns.com";
        $mail = mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_content);

        if($mail){echo "Success!";}else{echo "Something went wrong, please try again later.";}
    ?>
```

or if you just want to let please send a mail themselves i suggest you use this:

```
    <a href="mailto:suzanne@nielsenwebdesigns.com">Click here to send me a mail</a>
```